# Bash: From ./ move all directories' contents to their respective ../

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I have a list of 20 directories, each one has another directory with the contents I need (i.e. the contents are needlessly one level deeper than they need to be), the names of each super-directory is different to one another and their sub-directories are the same as their parent but without "_100bp" suffix:

**E.g. I have:** `directory_100bp/directory/<some content>`

**E.g. I need:** `directory_100bp/<some content>`

I know I can create a bash script to iterate for each directory:

```sh
mv ./directory/* ../
```

But is there a way I can do this one or two lines? I don't mind if the empty sub-directory remains after moving the contents one level up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your top level directory is named `mydir`:

```
find mydir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'mv {}/* mydir; rm -ri {}' \;
```

This will prompt you for each directory, you can change the `-i` flag to `-f` to force deletion without prompting.

Comment: Hi @Josh Jolly I should have made this clear, but the names of the directories one level lower are the same as their parent, but without "_100bp" at the ends. Would your command work with that?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. The command works by listing all the directories that are direct children of the top directory, then moving everything inside them into the top directory (preserving any hierarchies within). As long as there are no filename collisions, there should be no problems.

Comment: In `find`, `{}` is not supposed to used this way at all. I know it is specifically stated somewhere in the `find` manual that `{}` is a safe argument to use... **but it is safe to use as an _argument_ on its own** and you should not compose it like so. Your command breaks for filenames with spaces, and is devastating if there's a file named `*`. Quoting the `{}` will not help either. The proper way to write your command is: `find mydir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'mv "$0"/* mydir; rm -ri "$0"' {} \;`. Using `{}` as an argument to a `bash -c` will make it available as `$0`.